# Pasar campos de una TABLA a una caja de texto JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript

Buen día.
Estimados solicito de su ayuda con el siguiente caso.
¿Cómo puedo  pasar los campos de la columna **EQUIPOS** y **PUNTAJE** a las cajas de texto,según el orden de los campos de la tabla.
Estoy tratando de realizarlo desde una función en javascript.
Mi código es el siguiente:

```js
function calcular(){       
                // declaracion de variables
                var pts = document.querySelectorAll("td[data-title='PTS']");         
                var equipo = document.querySelectorAll("td[data-title='Equipo']");
            
                var arreglo= [];
                // crear array objeto con finalista
               
                for (var i = 0; i < pts.length;i++) {
                      
                    arreglo.push({"equipo":equipo[i].innerHTML,"pts":pts[i].innerHTML});
                    
                   console.log(arreglo);
                }
             
           
                // funcion para ordenar objeto array
                 arreglo.sort(function (a,b) {
                    if (a.pts < b.pts) {
                        return 1;
                    }
                 
                  if (a.pts > b.pts) {
                     return -1;
                    }
                    // a must be equal to b
                    return 0;
                });
            
                    // Salida / construccion de contenido
                    contenido ='Primer Lugar: ' + arreglo[0].equipo + ' PTS: ' + arreglo[0].pts;
                    contenido+='Segundo Lugar: ' + arreglo[1].equipo + ' PTS: ' + arreglo[1].pts;
                    contenido+='Tercer Lugar: ' + arreglo[2].equipo + ' PTS: ' + arreglo[2].pts;
                     
                     alert(contenido);
                     
       }
```

```html
ESTE ES MI CODIGO HTML QUE ESTOY UTILIZANDO.

<html>
  <head>
  </head>
    
  <body>
      <form>
          <label>EQUIPOS</label>
      <input type="text" name="txtequipor" id="erojo">
          <input type="text" name="txtequipoa" id="eamarillo">
                 <input type="text" name="txtequipot" id="eturqueza">
          
      </form>
<table id="datos">
                              <thead>
        
                    <tr>
                      
                        <th>Categoria</th>
                        <th>Genero</th>
                        <th>Equipo</th>
                        <th>PJ</th>
                        <th>PG</th>
                        <th>PP</th>
                        <th >PE</th>
                        <th>GF</th>
                        <th>GC</th>
                        <th>DFG</th>
                        <th>PTS</th>
                        <th>Calcular Ganador</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                
                    <tbody>
                               
                              
                                        <tr>
                 
                    <td data-title="Categoria">CAT 3</td>
                    <td data-title="Genero">V</td>
                   <td data-title="Equipo">ROJO</td>
                    <td  data-title="PJ">2</td>
                    <td  data-title="PG">1</td>
                    <td data-title="PP">1</td>
                    <td  data-title="PE">0</td>
                    <td  data-title="GF">3</td>
                    <td  data-title="GC">4</td>
                    <td  data-title="DFG">-1</td>
                     <td id="pts" data-title="PTS">3</td>
                                            <td rowspan="3"><input type="button" value="Pasar" class="pasar" onclick="calcular()"></td>
                     
                        </tr>
                                          <tr>
                 
                    <td data-title="Categoria">CAT 3</td>
                    <td data-title="Genero">V</td>
                   <td data-title="Equipo">AMARILLO</td>
                    <td  data-title="PJ">2</td>
                    <td  data-title="PG">2</td>
                    <td data-title="PP">0</td>
                    <td  data-title="PE">0</td>
                    <td  data-title="GF">7</td>
                    <td  data-title="GC">1</td>
                    <td  data-title="DFG">6</td>
                     <td id="pts"  data-title="PTS">6</td>
                                         
                     
                        </tr>
                                                  <tr>
                   
                    <td data-title="Categoria">CAT 3</td>
                    <td data-title="Genero">V</td>
                   <td data-title="Equipo">TURQUESA</td>
                    <td  data-title="PJ">2</td>
                    <td  data-title="PG">0</td>
                    <td data-title="PP">2</td>
                    <td  data-title="PE">0</td>
                    <td  data-title="GF">1</td>
                    <td  data-title="GC">6</td>
                    <td  data-title="DFG">-5</td>
                     <td id="pts" data-title="PTS">0</td>
                                         
                     
                        </tr>
            </tbody>
                    
                 </table>
      <script src="calcular.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Hasta el momento he realizado el cálculo de quién quedó primer,segundo y tercer lugar, pero ahora quiero pasar los equipos y los puntos a las cajas de texto según el orden de la tabla.

**Más o menos quedaría así:**

*caja de texto 1 equipo rojo más su puntaje 3*
*caja de texto 2 equipo amarillo mas su puntaje 6*
*caja de texto 3 equipo turqueza mas su puntaje 0*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He limpiado tu código y le he dado formato.

Lo que he hecho ha sido cambiarle el `id` en los `input` a un número para que puedan ser accesibles mediante el índice del array que estás recorriendo.

Luego para cada iteración del bucle  `for` modifico el `value` del input correspondiente a ese equipo con la información que hay almacenada en ese índice.

```
document.getElementById(i+1).value = 'Equipo: ' + arreglo[i].equipo + ' - puntos: ' + arreglo[i].pts;
```

Solución: (**código editado según nuevas preguntas del OP**)

```js
function calcular() {
    // declaracion de variables
    var pts = document.querySelectorAll("td[data-title='PTS']");
    var equipo = document.querySelectorAll("td[data-title='Equipo']");
    document.getElementById("contenido").innerHTML = '';

    var arreglo = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < pts.length; i++) {
        arreglo.push({
            "equipo": equipo[i].innerHTML,
            "pts": pts[i].innerHTML
        });
    }

    // funcion para ordenar objeto array por pts
    arreglo.sort(function (a, b) {
        if (a.pts < b.pts) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (a.pts > b.pts) {
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    });
    
    // cambiamos el valor a los pts
    var maxPuntuacion = 30; 
    for (var i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++) {
        arreglo[i].pts = maxPuntuacion; 
        maxPuntuacion -= 10;
        document.getElementById(arreglo[i].equipo).value = 'Equipo: ' + arreglo[i].equipo + ' - puntos: ' + arreglo[i].pts;
    }
    
    // Salida / construccion de contenido
    document.getElementById("contenido").innerHTML += '<p>Primer Lugar: ' + arreglo[0].equipo + ' PTS: ' + arreglo[0].pts + '</p>';
    document.getElementById("contenido").innerHTML += '<p>Segundo Lugar: ' + arreglo[1].equipo + ' PTS: ' + arreglo[1].pts + '</p>';
    document.getElementById("contenido").innerHTML += '<p>Tercer Lugar: ' + arreglo[2].equipo + ' PTS: ' + arreglo[2].pts + '</p>';

}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <label>EQUIPOS</label>
        <input type="text" name="txtequipor" id="ROJO">
        <input type="text" name="txtequipoa" id="AMARILLO">
        <input type="text" name="txtequipot" id="TURQUESA">
    </form>
    <table id="datos">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Categoria</th>
                <th>Genero</th>
                <th>Equipo</th>
                <th>PJ</th>
                <th>PG</th>
                <th>PP</th>
                <th>PE</th>
                <th>GF</th>
                <th>GC</th>
                <th>DFG</th>
                <th>PTS</th>
                <th>Calcular Ganador</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>

            <tr>
                <td data-title="Categoria">CAT 3</td>
                <td data-title="Genero">V</td>
                <td data-title="Equipo">ROJO</td>
                <td data-title="PJ">2</td>
                <td data-title="PG">1</td>
                <td data-title="PP">1</td>
                <td data-title="PE">0</td>
                <td data-title="GF">3</td>
                <td data-title="GC">4</td>
                <td data-title="DFG">-1</td>
                <td id="pts" data-title="PTS">3</td>
                <td rowspan="3"><input type="button" value="Pasar" class="pasar" onclick="calcular()"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td data-title="Categoria">CAT 3</td>
                <td data-title="Genero">V</td>
                <td data-title="Equipo">AMARILLO</td>
                <td data-title="PJ">2</td>
                <td data-title="PG">2</td>
                <td data-title="PP">0</td>
                <td data-title="PE">0</td>
                <td data-title="GF">7</td>
                <td data-title="GC">1</td>
                <td data-title="DFG">6</td>
                <td id="pts" data-title="PTS">6</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td data-title="Categoria">CAT 3</td>
                <td data-title="Genero">V</td>
                <td data-title="Equipo">TURQUESA</td>
                <td data-title="PJ">2</td>
                <td data-title="PG">0</td>
                <td data-title="PP">2</td>
                <td data-title="PE">0</td>
                <td data-title="GF">1</td>
                <td data-title="GC">6</td>
                <td data-title="DFG">-5</td>
                <td id="pts" data-title="PTS">0</td>
            </tr>
           
            <div id="contenido">
            
            </div>
        </tbody>

    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: eh aplicado la funcion y va bien,tengo otra consulta como puedo asignarle a la columna "PTS" si el primer valor es mayor asignarle = 30 puntos,y si es menor = 20 y si queda ultimo = 10 a la vez pasarlo al input en lugar de pasar  3 - 6 - 0 que es su puntaje correcto pasar estos puntajes 30 20 10 dependiendo del calculo.

Comment: Si quieres actualizar los datos de la tabla sin recargar la página tienes que usar `ajax`. Por otro lado he editado la respuesta inicial y te he dejado en la parte de `JavaScript` las modificaciones hechas con comentarios para que entiendas el proceso.

Comment: hay una parte que no me explique bien,si es bien cierto con la modificacion obtenimos el primer y segundo y tercer lugar.              Pero lo estoy tratando de hacer es cuando se pasan a los inputs  se pase de forma ordenada por ejemplo: en la primera parte se pasaba los equipos y su puntaje de forma ordenada pero en lugar de pasar ROJO PTS 3,AMARILLO PTS 6,TURQUEZA PTS 0 - SE PASE ASI ROJO PTS 20,AMARILLO PTS 30,TURQUEZA PTS 10 . espero tu gentil apoyo y gracias.

Comment: He vuelto a editar el código, prueba a ejecutarlo. ¿Es eso lo que estabas buscando?

Comment: perfecto estimado,quedo a la perfeccion muchas gracias por compartir tus sabios conocimiento voy a leer mas lo que es javascript.

Comment: hola estoy teniendo problemas en separar los puntos a otro input,porque segun la funcion tanto el equipo y el puntaje estan dentro del mismo input. por favor tu apoyo:

Comment: Por favor, crea otra pregunta y explícalo detalladamente. Añade el código nuevo que ya tienes.

Comment: ya lo publique espero su apoyo,gracias de todas maneras.